# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Estoy realizando un programa que me permita visualizar unos parametrós de unas bocinas, pero al momento que se opera el arreglo llamado u, me sale el error TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. ¿Como podría solucionar este problema?

Este es el código

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

st = int(input("Area"))
l = int(input("Longitud"))
xo=int(input("gar-org"))
m = int(input("Ensanchamiento"))
M = int(input("Factor"))
sx=[]
x=[]
ls=l+1
rho = 1.2
c = 340
for i in range(ls):
      s=st*((i/xo)**2)
      sx.append(s)
      x.append(i)
x1= np.array((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
fs = np.array((20,31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 20000))
u=np.array(fs/20)
ks = (2 * np.pi * fs) / c
zmr1=1j*((rho*c)/st)
zmr2=((1/u)*math.sqrt((1/u**2)-(1)))
zmr3=1-(1-((1-M**2)/(u**2)))
zmr =zmr1*(zmr2/zmr3)
real = np.real(zmr)
imaginaria = np.imag(zmr)
plt.plot(ff,real,"b--")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `math.sqrt` está pensada para operar sobre **un** escalar o en su defecto, sobre algo que se pueda convertir en uno. El problema es que tu lo aplicas sobre un array de NumPy que tiene más de un item en:

```
zmr2=((1/u)*math.sqrt((1/u**2)-(1)))
```

Ante ésto intenta convertir el array en un escalar dentro de los tipos nativos de Python, de hecho puedes reproducir el error de forma muy simple:

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
>
> >>> arr = np.array([1, 2])
> >>> float(arr)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "main", line 4, in <module>
>     float(arr)
>
> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
> ```

Si quieres aplicar la raíz cuadrada sobre cada uno de los elementos del array (lo que se conoce como vectorizar), debes usar `numpy.sqrt` no `math.sqrt`:

```
zmr2 = (1 / u) * np.sqrt((1/u ** 2) - 1)
```

también podrías iterar sobre el array y aplicar `math.sqrt` sobre cada item, pero es una soberana tontería dado que NumPy ofrece la versión vectorial de la misma función.

Pasa igual con cualquier otra función de `math`, como `log`, `sin`, etc.